Why would an escrow/title company not accept ACH payments?
I've recently entered into the escrow relationship for a home purchase and I'm seeing the following language show up in an email.

Please do NOT send an Electronic "ACH" transfer, as our bank does not accept these.

I'm curious why a bank would not have this capability for funds transfers? Is there fee or technology demands getting ACH payments set up? Why would someone chose not to accept this form of payment? In case it's context dependent, this email was in response to getting the earnest money deposit setup.

The answers are good, but another aspect of this is that a wire transfer is also a legal contract to an extent.  The bank is essentially entering into a contract with you that they WILL make every effort to deliver the funds to the beneficiary on or before a specific date.  If the bank fails on this, then they can be held liable for potential losses or damages caused to the parties involved.  ACH and other forms of electronic payment have no such guarantees, which is another reason why payments associated with legal contracts and titles are preferred to be wires.

@maple_shaft Not true. The bank has the same liability if they fail to properly pay a check or ACH, UCC 4-402 and 4A-305, respectively, and EFT Act 15 USC 1693h(a).

Because ACH payments are reversible.
Title companies are going to require a wire transfer because those payments are not reversible.  Which is also why you will receive several documents and emails telling you to beware of scammers contacting you as your closing date approaches with "updated" instructions for where to wire the money.  If you fall for one of those scams and wire the money to the wrong account, your bank can't reverse the transaction for you.

Popular opinion is that wires are not reversible, however this is not entirely true.  If you identify the fraud quickly enough, the bank CAN issue a reversal request and if the funds are still available at the beneficiary account then the request will be honored. You might get lucky, but probably not.  This is partly why wire fraud is treated so seriously by law enforcement.

@maple_shaft Generally the title company will, after receiving the wire, put the funds in to an escrow account. Once that is done the originating bank wouldn't be able to reverse the request without the consent of the title company. This is the entire point of the process and why the title company requires "good funds" be provided (either by wire or cashiers check), it provides certainty.


In case it's context dependent, this email was in response to getting
the earnest money deposit setup.

The earnest money deposit is to convince the seller that your offer is to be taken seriously, because you can forfeit the money if you back out of the deal unless it is one of the agreed conditions.
The bank that is going to hold the funds wants to limit your ability to pullback the funds. They will only release the funds back to the bidder or to the settlement process based on the written instructions from all parties.

Please do NOT send an Electronic "ACH" transfer, as our bank does not accept these.

They should have specified your options regarding these funds. I have seen cases where the funds could be paid by regular check, and cases when it has to be a certified check.
